# How to remove "justifyfull" in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

In my functions.php I have following:

```
function myplugin_tinymce_buttons_2($buttons)
{

  $remove = array('formatselect', 'justifyfull', 'forecolor');

  return array_diff($buttons,$remove);
}
add_filter('mce_buttons_2','myplugin_tinymce_buttons_2');
```

The dropdown style menu and color selector are succesfully gone, but the align justify -button sticks. I have tried 'alignfull', 'justify' and 'full', but nothing seems to remove it.

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Have you tried `alignjustify`?

Comment: No I had not. Write answer, I accept. Cheers!